# Accessing Office365 Sharepoint REST EndPoints using Python (Office365 Sharepoint REST client for Python)

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint, office365

I am trying to get access to a Sharepoint site from Python and it seems like AADSTS has a conditional access policy that’s preventing me from getting a token.

Has anyone used the Office365 Python Rest Client to successful connect to a Sharepoint Rest Endpoint?

This is the actual error I am seeing

```
"C:\Python\envs\dev\python.exe c:\Users\xxxxxx.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.105369\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher 52801 -- c:\xxxx\Code\PythonSharepointUpdate\readsharepoint.py " An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance. An error occurred while retrieving auth cookies from https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/
```

```
I am trying to execute this code from the Sample

    from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential 
    from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext 
    from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext 
    site_url = 'https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/' 
    ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(UserCredential("user@domain.com", "My Complex Password”)) 
    web = ctx.web 
    ctx.load(web) 
    ctx.execute_query() 
    print("Web title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))
```

Also – is there a better way to authenticate to Sharepoint – I hate to have to type my Password in clear text in code ☹

Has anyone use ClientCredential? Is there a seperate setup on the Sharepoint Site to enable ClientCredential? Does our Sharepoint let us do that?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use ClientCredentials and not UserCredentials.

One will have to create a new app on the Sharepoint site with a new CliendID and Client Secret. After creating a new app, the newly created app has to be given permissions on the site. Once the permissions are set, you will have to Trust the app.

The full explanation and the steps are documented here https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/wiki/How-to-connect-to-SharePoint-Online-and-and-SharePoint-2013-2016-2019-on-premises--with-app-principal